# Partially hide words in h1

Tags: html, css

I have a simple two-word header, from which I would like to remove or hide the last word, instead of wrapping it to the next line, when there is not enough room in the window for both words.

`<h1>First Last</h1>`

I know that there are no first-word selectors for css, so that's not an option. I could hide the overflow, but I want the last word to disappear all at once, not letter by letter. And of course, `white-space:nowrap;` comes to mind, but that doesn't remove the word.

Is there a way to do this with css? Preferably without fixed heights or widths?

http://jsfiddle.net/pnaL4/2/

Comment: have you tried `text-overflow: ellipsis;`? http://jsbin.com/epihik/1/edit

Comment: @balexandre, Yeah, it's what I'm using now, but in this case the ellipsis looks rather ugly in the site title, and only using the first word makes sense because it's a first name. So that's why I'd rather just have the first word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no possibility to select a last word from a tag. The only possibility I could think of was to use a [media query](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) that loads this custom CSS when the line size is too small:

```
h1 {
   visibility: hidden;
}

h1:before {
    visibility: visible;
    content: "First";
}
```

Of course, this would require you to specify the showed content.

Comment: Ah, why didn't I think of that! I think I'll adapt this slightly, and surround the last word with a span, that way I won't have to use generated content.

Comment: On second thought, your solution is more elegant. By the way, I found that I had to add `font-size:0;` to the h1 to stop it taking up space.

Answer (score 2):

Simple. Use a `white-space:nowrap;` CSS Property.

```
h1 {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This will ensure that even if the window resizes, the text will not wrap down and get hidden as the window shrinks.

Here is the **[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pnaL4/3/)** to illustrate the issue.

Comment: Funny, I was just adding that to the question. Great minds think alike :). It is an improvement, but it doesn't cut the word off (I could use overflow:hidden, but that leaves bits of the last word, doesn't remove the whole word).

Comment: yeah.. Indeed a good coincidence. That is true. Overflow:hidden can be a good option, but again, it is just the code snipped that we are viewing, but not the full HTML that is going to be generated. You can use media queries.

Answer (score 1):

I ususally do something like

```
h1 {
  font-size: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 745px;
```

}

ellipsis outputs ... to show there is more text to come, if you don't want anything at all I would do

```
text-overflow: inherit;
```

another good tip if you are cutting of text is to add a title attribute to the h1 so that the user can see the full word on hover.

eg

```
<h1 title="First Last">First Last</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you let the overflowing word(s) break to the next line, you can use an overflow with a height instead of width to create that effect:

```
h1 {
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/PwYLz/)